# How to return stories of type 'bug' from PivotalTracker

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, pivotaltracker

I am using Python 2.7 in conjunction with the requests module and the PivotalTracker API to make a GET request to retrieve the stories in a particular project. Here is the definition of the endpoint: http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/v5#projects_project_id_stories_get. So I am able to use this and get all the stories in the project, but I am trying to only get the stories of `type = bug`. This is what I've tried:

```
#project_id is my project ID and PTtoken is my API token

url = 'https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/{}/stories?fields=name,story_type,created_at&with_label=bug'
r = requests.get(url.format(project_id), headers={'X-TrackerToken':PTtoken})
```

This returns this error:

```
{"kind":"error","code":"invalid_parameter","general_problem":"this endpoint cannot accept the parameter: with_type","error":"One or more request parameters was missing or invalid."}
```

So obviously the `with_type=bug` is whats providing the error as it works fine without it. But reading through the documentation it seems to me like I should be able to refine my search based on the type. In the documentation it says this: "Searches can be refined with all of the modifications listed here: [How can a search be refined](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/faq#howcanasearchberefined)?" Upon clicking through to the link, it says I can search based on type.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!